# == null Doesn't work java

Tags: java

I have made a function for objects to reserve seats in a area. But if 2 objects enter the function at the same time they get the same seats. How do I solve this?

The Function getFreeChairs, returns the chair positions. And sets the Fan. But if two fans enter it at the same time they both get the same seats.

Sven

```
package model;

import actors.Fan;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by sveno on 12-10-2016.
 */
public class Vak {
    private static int autoId = 1;
    private String naam;
    private int rijen, stoelenperrij, id;
    private List<ArrayList> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    private Fan fan = null;

    public Vak(String naam, int rijen, int stoelenperrij) {
        this.naam = naam;
        this.rijen = rijen;
        this.stoelenperrij = stoelenperrij;
        this.id = autoId;
        autoId++;

        for (int i = 0; i < rijen; i++) {
            rows.add(new ArrayList<Fan>());
        }

        for (ArrayList row : rows) {
            for (int j = 0; j < stoelenperrij; j++) {
                row.add(fan);
            }
        }

    }
    public void removeReserved(int rij, List<Integer> stoelen){
        for (int i = 0; i < stoelen.size()-1; i++) {
            //De reserveer alle stoelen
            ArrayList<Fan> stoel = rows.get(rij);
            stoel.set(stoelen.get(i),fan);
        }
    }

    public int getRijen() {
        return rijen;
    }

    public int getStoelenperrij() {
        return stoelenperrij;
    }

    public List<ArrayList> getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public int[] getFreeChairs(int aantalStoelen, Fan fan){
        //Check for free seats
        int count = 1;
        int[] stoelenleeg = new int[aantalStoelen+1];
            for (int j = 0; j < rows.size(); j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < rows.get(j).size(); k++) {
                    if (rows.get(j).get(k) == null){
                        stoelenleeg[count-1] = k;
                        count++;
                        //Not enough seats next to each other
                        if(count==aantalStoelen+1){
                            stoelenleeg[aantalStoelen] = j+1;
                            for (int o = 0; o < stoelenleeg.length-1; o++) {
                                ArrayList<Fan> stoel = rows.get(j);
                                stoel.set(stoelenleeg[o],fan);
                            }
                            return stoelenleeg;
                        }
                    }else{
                        //Not enough seats
                        stoelenleeg = new int[aantalStoelen+1];
                        count=1;
                    }
                }
            }
        return stoelenleeg;
    }
}
```

Comment: By "enter at the same time", do you mean this application is multithreaded? If it is, then the issue is not that the null check is failing; it's that when two  threads read the same value around the same time, the result is non-deterministic. You will have to synchronize access to ensure that only one fan gets one seat.

Comment: Just a side note, but I don't think `static` class variables do what you think they do. That "autoId" is going to be the same for every single instance of this class, it's just going to essentially tell you how many you've created over time.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is used in a concurrent context (multiple threads), you need to make sure that your code is thread safe.
It means that, only one single thread(person) should be able to call the getFreeChairs function(reserve a seat at a time)
The easy way to do it in java is to use the synchronized key word in the method definition:

```
public synchronized int[] getFreeChairs(int aantalStoelen, Fan fan){
   ...
}
```